# ffmpeg -pattern_type blob does not preserve ordering

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm monitoring a mountain webcam that refreshes the image once a hour, and I want to do a timelapse of one year worth. The images are all saved with datetime names like `amiantheYYYYMMDDHHII.jpg` (e.g.: amianthe201911011730.jpg is the 17:30 image of the 1st november 2019). The nightly images aren't so interesting, so I'd like to filter them out. My current command is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -framerate 24 \
    -f image2 \
    -pattern_type glob -i 'amianthe????????{07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}??.jpg' \
    -r 24 \
    timelapse.mp4
```

The order isn't preserved: in the final video I have first all images of 7 in the morning, then 8, then 9... Inside the hour the order of days is correct, but it's not what I want.

Can I reorder the files with some glob options or shall I completely change the approach? If I try a

```
ls amianthe????????{07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}??.jpg
```

the order is correct, so it seems a problem of the ffmpeg implementation.
Any suggestion?

Comment: ffmpeg uses `glob()` which should respect `LC_COLLATE` sort order, so it should be the same as what you're getting with `ls`…

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but practical experience says "no": it seems that all `07` files are ordered by collation, _then_ all `08`, _then_ all `09`... There's not a single sort at the end of filtering.

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround would be to use an input file:

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -f concat \
    -i input.txt
    -r 24 \
    timelapse.mp4
```

Create the input file with:

```
for f in amianthe????????{07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}??.jpg; do
    echo "file '$f'" >> input.txt
done
```

This should create entries with the filenames in correct oder, if `ls` gives you the same.

See [Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) for more options, or [Slideshow](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow) for examples of creating slideshows.

Comment: Turns out that I read the `ls` output wrong, it wasn't well ordered. I've slightly changed your solution:
```#!/bin/bash
rm -f input.txt

for f in $(ls ./amianthe????????{07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}??.jpg|sort -g -); do
    echo "file '$f'" >> input.txt
done

ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -f concat \
    -safe 0 \
    -i input.txt \
    -r 24 \
    timelapse.mp4```
The `-safe 0` was needed because the file was generated with `./`prefixes in filenames, and I've dropped the `-framerate 24` option because `concat` didn't support it.
If you change your solution I'll vote

Comment: Doing `for f in $(ls)` is a bad idea (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). So only `sort -g` is giving you the correct order?

Answer (score 1):

I've taken the solution of @slhck and worked on it. As stated in comments, turns out that the ordering from `ls` was bad either, so I needed to sort the results. To avoid a cycle through `ls` (that should be fine in this specific use case, but is generally avoidable) I used that wild beast called `sed` :-)

```
#!/bin/bash

ls amianthe????????{07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}??.jpg | sort -g | sed "s/\(.*\)/file '\1'/g" > input.txt

ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -f concat \
    -i input.txt \
    -r 24 \
    timelapse.mp4

rm -f input.txt
```